# Finding the source of LNK1104's filename

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, houdini, usd

I'm working in a Visual Studio Project that was generated using CMake, and for some reason, I get an LNK1104 error on build saying "cannot open file 'hboost_python27-vc142-mt-x64-1_72.lib'" and I know for a **fact** that that file does not exist anywhere and that the correct dependency is "hboost_python27-mt-x64.lib." So why is Visual Studio asking for this file? How would I go about deriving where this filename is coming from, and then fixing it? Is this more of a CMake issue? Or a Visual Studio issue?

For reference, I'm compiling a custom USD Asset Resolver for Houdini, and here is the code I was working on https://github.com/mwalk176/USD-Custom-Resolver-Windows-Example/tree/main/custom_resolver/project

Comment: Probably a `#pragma comment (lib ...` in the headers.

Comment: Note that USD itself has a dependency on boost. Do not mix different boost libraries. Use [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) instead.

Comment: I'm trying to compile it against Houdini's internal implementation of USD and boost, but would that still require vcpkg?

Comment: The only #pragma comment is a `#pragma once` in the main header of my code, would that cause it?

Comment: @drescherjm Update: Found a `#pragma comment (lib...)` in one of the included header files that seems to be causing it. It has the format `pragma comment(lib, HBOOST_LIB_PREFIX HBOOST_STRINGIZE(HBOOST_LIB_NAME) "-" HBOOST_LIB_TOOLSET HBOOST_LIB_THREAD_OPT HBOOST_LIB_RT_OPT HBOOST_LIB_ARCH_AND_MODEL_OPT "-" HBOOST_LIB_VERSION ".lib")`, how would I set these variables within the VS2019 environment?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have quite old version of Boost installed on your PC, starting from quite recent versions of Boost it is a standard way to write more verbose syntax like `hboost_python27-vc142-mt-x64-1_72.lib`, so it is correct.

Try downloading Boost 1.72 [from here](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_72_0.html) or if your code is compatible with more recent versions of Boost then it is better to download latest version which is [1.78 download](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_78_0.html) right now.

Otherwise in your file system copy file `hboost_python27-mt-x64.lib` over to `hboost_python27-vc142-mt-x64-1_72.lib`, or make Windows hard link. This way it will be found when compiling.

Another option is that you modify your current code

```cpp
#pragma comment(lib, HBOOST_LIB_PREFIX HBOOST_STRINGIZE(HBOOST_LIB_NAME) "-" \
    HBOOST_LIB_TOOLSET HBOOST_LIB_THREAD_OPT HBOOST_LIB_RT_OPT \
    HBOOST_LIB_ARCH_AND_MODEL_OPT "-" HBOOST_LIB_VERSION ".lib")
```

to shorter version:

```cpp
#pragma comment(lib, HBOOST_LIB_PREFIX HBOOST_STRINGIZE(HBOOST_LIB_NAME) "-" \
    HBOOST_LIB_THREAD_OPT HBOOST_LIB_RT_OPT HBOOST_LIB_ARCH_AND_MODEL_OPT ".lib")
```

after this change this pragma code will produce expected file name `hboost_python27-mt-x64.lib`.